# trying to run sample app with spark-submit but getting class not found excpetion

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to run example from [learning spark](https://github.com/databricks/learning-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/scala/StreamingLogInput.scala) book

```
package com.example

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}


import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream._

object SimpleExample {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val master = args(0)
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(master).setAppName("StreamingLogInput")
    // Create a StreamingContext with a 1 second batch size
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
    // Create a DStream from all the input on port 7777
    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 7777)
    val errorLines = processLines(lines)
    // Print out the lines with errors, which causes this DStream to be evaluated
    errorLines.print()
    // start our streaming context and wait for it to "finish"
    ssc.start()
    // Wait for 10 seconds then exit. To run forever call without a timeout
    ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(10000)
    ssc.stop()
  }
  def processLines(lines: DStream[String]) = {
    // Filter our DStream for lines with "error"
    lines.filter(_.contains("error"))
  }

}
```

using maven project this is my pom.xml

```
<project>
    <groupId>com.streaming.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>streaming-example</artifactId>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>example</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <args>
                            <!-- work-around for https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8358 -->
                            <arg>-nobootcp</arg>
                        </args>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

**but when running it like this :**

```
> spark-submit --class src/scala/com/example/SimpleExample.scala \
> target/streaming-example-0.0.1.jar local[4]
```

**I am getting this error :**

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src/scala/com/example/SimpleExample
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

**EDIT jar content :**

```
$ jar tf target/streaming-example-0.0.1.jar 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/com.streaming.example/
META-INF/maven/com.streaming.example/streaming-example/
META-INF/maven/com.streaming.example/streaming-example/pom.xml
```

Comment: Did you check if the class is in the package generated by jar via `unzip -l <target>.jar`? Also, try sbt.

Comment: @Reactormonk, not sure that I got you. it was generated using mvn clean package

Comment: take a look at the generated jar if it actually contains the class.

Comment: @Reactormonk, It seems to exists. 
$ jar tf target/streaming-example-0.0.1.jar 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/com.streaming.example/
META-INF/maven/com.streaming.example/streaming-example/
META-INF/maven/com.streaming.example/streaming-example/pom.xml

Comment: What seems to exist? Your SimpleExample.class isn't in your jar! How are you compiling your application?

Comment: @eliasah , you are correct . I missed that . the problem was in the pom missing the correct plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SimpleExample.class isn't in your jar.

Check your maven build plugins.

You may consider using the assembly plugin and compiling with :

```
mvn assembly:assembly
```

As it create an uber-jar the will contain all your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the file path, the --class argument looks for the package structure. Try this:

```
spark-submit --class com.example.SimpleExample target/streaming-example-0.0.1.jar
```

Comment: Tried that , still the same .